# Rich edit control sends EN_CHANGE when spellcheck underline appears

Tags: c++, winapi, atl, richedit, richedit-control

Let's say you've just set some text in a spellcheck-enabled rich edit control, and the text has some spelling errors. A split second will go by, spellcheck will kick in, and then the misspelled text will get underlined.  But guess what: the rich edit control will actually send an `EN_CHANGE` notification just for the underlining event (this is assuming you've registered for notifications by doing `SendMessage(hwnd, EM_SETEVENTMASK, 0, (LPARAM)ENM_CHANGE)`).

Is there a workaround to not get this type of behavior?  I've got a dialog with some spellcheck-enabled rich edit controls.  And I also want to know when an edit event has taken place, so I know when to enable the "Save" button.  Getting an `EN_CHANGE` notification merely for the spellcheck underlining event is thus a problem.

One option I've considered is disabling  `EN_CHANGE` notifications entirely, and then triggering them on my own in a subclassed rich edit control.  For example, when there's a `WM_CHAR`, it would send the  `EN_CHANGE` notification explicitly, etc.  But that seems like a problem, because there are many types of events that should trigger changes, like deletes, copy/pastes, etc., and I'd probably not capture all of them correctly.

Another option I've considered is enabling and disabling `EN_CHANGE` notifications dynamically.  For example, enabling them only when there's focus, and disabling when focus is killed.  But that also seems problematic, because a rich edit might already have focus when its text is set.  Then the spellcheck underline would occur, and the undesirable `EN_CHANGE` notification would be sent.

I suppose a timer could be used, too, but I think that would be highly error-prone.

Does anybody have any other ideas?

Here's a reproducible example.  Simply run it, and it'll say something changed:

```
#include <Windows.h>
#include <atlbase.h>
#include <atlwin.h>
#include <atltypes.h>
#include <Richedit.h>

class CMyWindow :
    public CWindowImpl<CMyWindow, CWindow, CWinTraits<WS_VISIBLE>>
{
public:
    CMyWindow()
    {
    }

BEGIN_MSG_MAP(CMyWindow)
    MESSAGE_HANDLER(WM_CREATE, OnCreate)
    COMMAND_CODE_HANDLER(EN_CHANGE, OnChange)
END_MSG_MAP()

private:
    LRESULT OnCreate(UINT, WPARAM, LPARAM, BOOL& bHandled)
    {
        bHandled = FALSE;

        LoadLibrary(L"Msftedit.dll");

        CRect rc;
        GetClientRect(&rc);
        m_wndRichEdit.Create(MSFTEDIT_CLASS, m_hWnd, &rc,
            NULL, WS_VISIBLE | WS_CHILD | WS_BORDER);

        INT iLangOpts = m_wndRichEdit.SendMessage(EM_GETLANGOPTIONS, NULL, NULL);
        iLangOpts |= IMF_SPELLCHECKING;
        m_wndRichEdit.SendMessage(EM_SETLANGOPTIONS, NULL, (LPARAM)iLangOpts);

        m_wndRichEdit.SetWindowText(L"sdflajlf adlfjldsfklj dfsl");
       
        m_wndRichEdit.SendMessage(EM_SETEVENTMASK, 0, (LPARAM)ENM_CHANGE);
      
        return 0;
    }

    LRESULT OnChange(WORD, WORD, HWND, BOOL&)
    {
        MessageBox(L"changed", NULL, NULL);
        return 0;
    }

private:
    CWindow m_wndRichEdit;
};


int APIENTRY wWinMain(_In_ HINSTANCE hInstance,
                     _In_opt_ HINSTANCE hPrevInstance,
                     _In_ LPWSTR    lpCmdLine,
                     _In_ int       nCmdShow)
{
    CMyWindow wnd;
    CRect rc(0, 0, 200, 200);
    wnd.Create(NULL, &rc);

    MSG msg;
    while (GetMessage(&msg, nullptr, 0, 0))
    {
        TranslateMessage(&msg);
        DispatchMessage(&msg);
    }

    return (int)msg.wParam;
}
```

Also, it appears that using `EM_SETMODIFY` and `EM_GETMODIFY` don't help.  I guess the spellcheck underlining results in a `EM_SETMODIFY`, so checking that flag in the handler is of no avail.

Comment: Can you just keep a 'private' copy of the text in the edit control and then, when you get the `EN_CHANGE` notification, check to see if the text has *actually* changed before you enable your "Save" button? A `GetWindowtext()` call would let you know what the current content is.

Comment: @AdrianMole Do you mean for the parent dialog to keep a private copy?  I suppose that's possible, but of course then it has to keep a copy for every rich edit control and compare accordingly.

Comment: @AdrianMole That's actually harder than you might think.  Some or all of the text on a rich edit control can be emboldened, for example and that 'boldness' forms part of the control's state.  Maybe that can be resolved by streaming the contents of the rich edit control to a memory buffer as RTF though, see: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/em-streamout.

Comment: you got pointer to [`CHANGENOTIFY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/textserv/ns-textserv-changenotify) structure in *lParam*. so you simply need check *dwChangeType* member and do action based on it. all is very simply

Comment: @RbMm Contrary to the documentation, the rich edit actually sends a `WM_COMMAND`, not `WM_NOTIFY`.  So that `CHANGENOTIFY` structure is not available.

Comment: Can [EN_STARTCOMPOSITION](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/en-startcomposition) help you? Such a save button don't need to be too precise. or as @Adrian Mole said, you can keep a 'private' copy and then compare by yourself.

Comment: @RemyLebeau Well it actually sends a `WM_COMMMAND` notification, not `WM_NOTIFY`.  I think `WM_NOTIFY` is sent by "windowless" rich edit controls.  https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/en-change--rich-edit-control-

Comment: and what is bad for you in solution with tracking `WM_TIMER` in richedit ?

Comment: Well according to these docs, both the plain edit and the rich edit send the `EN_CHANGE` as part of `WM_COMMAND`: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/controls/en-change

Answer (score 1, accepted):

because documentation about [`CHANGENOTIFY`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/windows/win32/api/textserv/ns-textserv-changenotify) ( *must contains information that is associated with an EN_CHANGE notification code, but not..*) is wrong - only research exist.

in my test i view that `EN_CHANGE` related to Spellcheck received only when rich edit handle `WM_TIMER` message. so solution is next - subclass richedit and remember (save in class member variable) - when it inside `WM_TIMER`. than, when we handle `EN_CHANGE` - check are richedit inside `WM_TIMER`.

partial POC code. i special show more complex case - if several (more than one) child richedit`s exist in frame or dialog winndow

```
#include <richedit.h>

class RichFrame : public ZFrameMultiWnd
{
    enum { richIdBase = 0x1234 };
    bool _bInTimer[2] = {};

public:
protected:
private:
    static LRESULT WINAPI SubclassProc(HWND hWnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam, UINT_PTR uIdSubclass, DWORD_PTR dwRefData)
    {
        if ((uIdSubclass -= richIdBase) >= _countof(_bInTimer))
        {
            __debugbreak();
        }

        bool bTimerMessage = uMsg == WM_TIMER;
        
        if (bTimerMessage)
        {
            reinterpret_cast<RichFrame*>(dwRefData)->_bInTimer[uIdSubclass] = TRUE;
        }
        
        lParam = DefSubclassProc(hWnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);

        if (bTimerMessage)
        {
            reinterpret_cast<RichFrame*>(dwRefData)->_bInTimer[uIdSubclass] = false;
        }

        return lParam;
    }

    virtual BOOL CreateClient(HWND hWndParent, int nWidth, int nHeight, PVOID /*lpCreateParams*/)
    {
        UINT cy = nHeight / _countof(_bInTimer), y = 0;

        UINT id = richIdBase;
        ULONG n = _countof(_bInTimer);

        do 
        {
            if (HWND hwnd = CreateWindowExW(0, MSFTEDIT_CLASS, 0, WS_CHILD|ES_MULTILINE|WS_VISIBLE|WS_BORDER, 
                0, y, nWidth, cy, hWndParent, (HMENU)id, 0, 0))
            {
                SendMessage(hwnd, EM_SETLANGOPTIONS, 0, 
                    SendMessage(hwnd, EM_GETLANGOPTIONS, 0, 0) | IMF_SPELLCHECKING);

                SetWindowText(hwnd, L"sdflajlf adlfjldsfklj d");
                SendMessage(hwnd, EM_SETEVENTMASK, 0, ENM_CHANGE);

                if (SetWindowSubclass(hwnd, SubclassProc, id, reinterpret_cast<ULONG_PTR>(this)))
                {
                    continue;
                }
            }

            return FALSE;

        } while (y += cy, id++, --n);
        
        return TRUE;
    }

    virtual LRESULT WindowProc(HWND hwnd, UINT uMsg, WPARAM wParam, LPARAM lParam)
    {
        switch (uMsg)
        {
        case WM_COMMAND:
            if (EN_CHANGE == HIWORD(wParam))
            {
                if ((wParam = LOWORD(wParam) - richIdBase) >= _countof(_bInTimer))
                {
                    __debugbreak();
                }
                
                DbgPrint("EN_CHANGE<%x> = %x\n", wParam, _bInTimer[wParam]);
            }
            break;

        case WM_DESTROY:
            {
                UINT id = richIdBase;
                ULONG n = _countof(_bInTimer);
                do 
                {
                    RemoveWindowSubclass(GetDlgItem(hwnd, id), SubclassProc, id);
                } while (id++, --n);
            }
            break;

        case WM_NCDESTROY:
            PostQuitMessage(0);
            break;
        }
        return __super::WindowProc(hwnd, uMsg, wParam, lParam);
    }
};
```

Comment: But it seems that WM_TIMER is used a lot for a rich edit control, not just the spellchecker.  Isn't that going to be a problem?

Comment: @user15025873 - and how and why this can be problem ? are you test idea ?

Comment: If a `WM_TIMER` message is generated for more than one reason, it's hard to justify that observing a `WM_TIMER` message corresponds to a single reason.

Comment: @IInspectable - were you view that i say that `WM_TIMER` only for single reason ? i at all not assume this. but by fact spellchecker sent `EN_CHANGE` only from `WM_TIMER`. another `EN_CHANGE` send for instance from `WM_CHAR`. by fact this is good solution for view difference between different `EN_CHANGE`

Comment: visa versa. i not assume that WM_TIMER used only for check spelling, but i assume that check spelling use only WM_TIMER

Comment: @user15025873 - *drawback is that it requires the parent and child to have access to the same flag.* ?! what you mean under this ? no any drawback here at all. think my solution the best from possible

Comment: @user15025873 *I mean it seems to require the child subclass procedure to know information about the parent data/procedure.* - and ? so what ? we have this information as you can see. your alternative how minimum much more bad if working at all

Comment: @user15025873 - unclear what sense in subclass proc, send some messages, change properties, revert it back, when enough simply remember that now `WM_TIMER` processed

Comment: @user15025873 - but i special write code for this case ! look better/ in what problem ?! simply change  `bool _bInTimer[10] = {};` - 2 to 10.

Comment: @user15025873 - not difficult easy - my code **already** do this. -  every rich edit have own separate flag. even better use 1 bit instead bool (1 byte). i and _bittestandset, _bittestandreset, _bittest. i can change for this, simply not sure are exist sense

Comment: @user15025873 - in what problem ?! what you at all mean under *translate*

Comment: @user15025873 - https://pastebin.com/zRS1zUdJ if use 1 bit instead 1 byte for flag. but nothing basically not changed

Comment: Yes, this seems to work OK. WM_TIMER is also used for scrolling etc. but so far I have not found any other EN_CHANGE inside a WM_TIMER handler. Nice solution.

Answer (score 0):

Use `EM_CANUNDO` (maybe also `EM_CANREDO`) to verify that contents has changed. I hope that spellchecker does't add any undo information.

Comment: This was promising, but after experimenting, there are times when it'll still fail.  You can make some changes in an edit control, which will populate the undo queue.  Then if an underline suddenly appears at some point (and with the rich edit spellchecker, they appear at unexpected points in time), then the condition check will register true and give you a false positive.

Comment: There is also `EM_GETMODIFY`.

Comment: The spellchecker underline actually sets the modify flag, so that doesn't work either.

Answer (score 0):

I recently tried to work around this without subclassing but it was only somewhat successful.

My alternative workaround consists of marking the entire document as `CFE_PROTECTED`. In the `EN_PROTECTED` handler `ENPROTECTED::msg` is `WM_NULL` when coming from the spell checker and you can set a flag telling yourself to ignore the next `EN_CHANGE`. To allow actual spelling corrections from the context menu you also need to keep track of menus.

This feels rather fragile but so does tracking `WM_TIMER`.